# (How) Can one construct a Dirac equation analogue for photons?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, photons, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

So, the dirac equation exists

$$\hat{H} = -i\hbar c(\partial_x \gamma_1 + \partial_y \gamma_2 + \partial_z \gamma_3) + m c^2 \gamma_0$$

and describes spin 1/2 particles, and can be generalized to arbitrary gauge fields by modifying the momentum term.

The spin portion of the gamma matrices are built from the elements of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, which more intuitively describes spin 1/2 particles.

Say, getting rid of $mc^2\gamma_0$, could one rewrite the photon Hamiltonian for some other spin-1 $\hat{H}_{photon} = -i\hbar c(\mathbf{p}\cdot \mathbf{?})$ ? I suppose the elements of  "$\mathbf{?}$" would need to be higher dimensional than the Gamma matrices to describe the extra spin degrees of freedom, but I cannot find intuitive references on how one might do this.

Any insight would be appreciated!

My curiosity stems from the insight that it is very easy to build a tight-binding model for at least Weyl and Dirac electrons, and this captures all of the relevant spin physics. It'd be very cool to write the photon Hamiltonian in a way that is amenable to discretizing and putting it on a grid, to exploit all of this interesting chirality based physics that is emerging. Could also easily model photon transport in complex heterostructures after this.

Comment: But it has been seen that the quantum version of Maxwell's equations give wave functions for the photon https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0604169

Comment: Okay, sure I could use eq. 10), but would need to represent the hamiltonian as $\sigma_z \otimes \vec{\nabla} \times()$ if I wanted to model both chiralities at once. But this still doesn't generalize for spatially-varying chirality mixing terms, like what might show up in some complex photonic metamaterial. Surely there's some nice way to do all of this and account for photon spin.

Comment: Do you know [Proca equation](http://www.sp.u-tokai.ac.jp/~bentz/relateqm11.pdf)?

Comment: No, that looks like a great resource! thank you for sharing :)